# Create a page indicator using html, css and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular8

How can I create a page indicator like the one in the image? I have no idea where to start from.
The page can contain only 5 elements, all the others have to go to the following pages.

[image]

Comment: This is known as a pagination. Lots of different ways to go about it. But try researching it first and implementing some code yourself. Then if you are stuck, come back to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called pagination or sometimes just paging and there are many ways to implement it. Since you mentioned bootstrap in the title, here's the link to their documentation on the topic: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
 
<nav aria-label="Demo of active current page number">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Prev</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">6</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">7</a></li>                
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```